# Persisting data with redux-toolkit slices

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am fairly new to redux-toolkit but I am quite partial to using their slices. They seem like an easy enough way to create reducers.

I do not know, however, how to execute async operations after an action has been dispatched. My use-case is, that I need to update the state and then execute an async operation (or more generally an operation with side-effects).

How would one do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use redux saga for that. It will basically be listening to your action and call the async function whenever action is dispatched